# Showing that a map is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let  $h$ be a map from a topological space $Y$ to another topological space $Y'$. If $h(U)$ is open in $Y'$ for every open set $U$ in $Y$, then is $h$ continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Consider examples in which $Y$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: I know that a map $h$ in which $Y$ has the discrete topology is always continuous since for each open subset U of $Y'$, $h^-1(U)$ is open in$Y$; but i don't know how can i relate this with my question.

Comment: @rukiye: That’s exactly backwards. If $X$ has the discrete topology, than any map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous. If $Y$ has the discrete topology, then any map $f:X\to Y$ is ... ?

Comment: Then i can only say that for each open set $U$ in $X$ $f(U)$ will be open in $Y$.

Comment: @rukiye: Exactly. Which is the definition of $f$ being an open map. So *every* map to $Y$ is open. Now just find one that isn’t continuous.

Comment: @rukiye: Excellent. You’re welcome.